# Why spring mvc can not use the right encoding and contenttype

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc3 to build a web service:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/util", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public class UtilController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "xx";
    }
}
```

Now this controller worked with the request:

```
http://localhost:8080/util/
```

However, I meet two problems:

1 encoding

When I change the return value from `xx` to something else like Chinese characters, I will get the un readable result in the client.

2 content-type

Through the firbug, I got this:

```
Content-Length  2
Content-Type    text/html
Server  Jetty(6.1.26)
```

Why it is `text/html` rather than `text/plain`?

How to fix it?

Comment: I'm using 3.2.2 and could not reproduce the behavior you describe (I'm running it on a Tomcat instead of a Jetty, but that shouldn't make a difference). In your case it is as if the `produces` isn't there at all. Have you tried the basic stuff, like cleaning the project and recompiling? Also, if you put the `produces` in the method's `@RequestMapping`, does the error continue? Have you got a `HttpMessageConverter` somewhere else or something that may be overriding the headers?

Comment: In fact, I have only one controller in my project, I do not have any spring related beans configed. The error contiuned event I add the `produces` to the method. BTW, I am using the spring `3.2.1.RELEASE`, I dot not know if this is the problem. I wil try `3.2.2` again.

Comment: @hguser what's up? Did you figure it out? Did 3.2.2 help or managed to make it work in 3.2.1?